# Issues running the Unreal Engine 5.3 Spatial Anchors sample on Meta Quest 3 potentially due to AndroidFileClient

Tags: android, virtual-reality, oculus, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

I am trying to build the Spatial Anchors sample project on Unreal Engine 5.3 (Oculus-VR Source) but receiving an error message related to the AndroidFileClient. The Passthrough and Scene samples have built to my Meta Quest 3 without failure so I'm assuming it has something to do with the Spatial Anchors project needing to save anchors to the headset file system.

I am very new to Unreal so I apologize if this is a stupid question and I'm missing something obvious. I've been through the Meta documentation on this sample and have searched the web and can't find anything related or anyone else that has encountered this issue. I did not try this sample project on any previous versions of Unreal so I'm unsure if this is an issue with the new Oculus-VR build of UE5.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the relevant section of the output log when trying to build:

Running: C:\Users\Aleistor\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 2G0YC1ZF850S41 install -r "C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Samples\Oculus\SpatialAnchorsSample 5.3\Binaries/Android\SpatialAnchorsSample-arm64.apk"
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Performing Streamed Install
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Success
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Took 5.02s to run adb.exe, ExitCode=0
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Attempting to connect to file server [USB]
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Not connected, attempting to start file server
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Connected to RemoteFileManager
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Creating UECommandLine.txt
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Deploying files using AFS
LogPlayLevel: UAT: 0> Unexpected Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.Batch_Flush() in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 915
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.FileWrite(String SourcePath, String DestPath, Int32 bLog) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 2018
LogPlayLevel: UAT: SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.Batch_Flush() in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 915
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.Batch_Append(Byte[] packet, Int32 writeSize) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 945
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.SocketSend(Boolean bPayload, Byte[] packet) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 963
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.CloseConnection() in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 1777
LogPlayLevel: UAT: 0> Unexpected Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.Batch_Flush() in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 915
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.Batch_Append(Byte[] packet, Int32 writeSize) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 945
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.SocketSend(Boolean bPayload, Byte[] packet) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 963
LogPlayLevel: UAT:    at AutomationTool.AndroidFileClient.FileWrite(String SourcePath, String DestPath, Int32 bLog) in C:\Unreal Engine 5\UnrealEngine\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\Android\AndroidFileClient.cs:line 1992

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else facing this issue, I did the following and now it seems to be working:

1. Turned off Android File Server in project settings.
2. Built the project to APK.
3. Installed the project to the Quest 3 via ADB.

There were still some issues after this, but then I turned Android File Server back on and tried deploying it straight to the Quest 3 again and it seemed to work.